# Can I use different countries version of the Play Store on different accounts?

Tags: google-play-store, multi-user, accounts

I recently moved abroad and I need to change the country of my Play Store (for mobile/banking apps), I also need to keep the apps from my home country.

Can I use two different Android accounts (with two different Google account) each with their own countries? Will they interfere with each other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes. I have different accounts with a different country. It is working fine.